# mapkit doesn't showing default blue blob on device?

Tags: objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0, mapkit, user-location

I am using mapkit in my application.i want to show blue blob in mapview.i have set [mapview setShowUserLocation:YES]; but it doesn't showing blue blob.also it's cordinates are -180.0000,-180.0000? how is this happen? is there a bug in mapkit. i am not using location manager to show blue dot.i know that setting showuserlocation to yes will show the blue dot automatically.does someone know why blue blob having negative cordinates and how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The blue blob isn't default, it's specifically for the Google Maps application. If you want your annotation to show something on the map, you need to provide an MKAnnotationView for it. MapKit comes with the MKPinAnnotationView for free, where you can select a red, green or purple pin. If you want anything else to appear, you will have to provide your own custom view and your own custom art.

Comment: blue blob is by default in mapkit.i think you haven't used mapkit yet.by the way i found the problem,it was device problem.the device is not getting the location so the location of user is unable to locate.thus it shows user location cordinates to -180.000,-180.000

Answer (score 1):

```
if (annotation == aMapView.userLocation) 
{
    return nil; // this might be the moment the location was first detected
}
```